# File Preview in LWC is not working in Gmail (through Email Application Pane)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-for-gmail, email-application-pane

I have implemented a file preview feature in the lightning web component (LWC) by calling the following code which is **not working** when I access the component in **Gmail (through Email Application Pane).**

Not sure if this feature is not supported like this as **it's working fine when the LWC component is placed on the standard record page.**

I would really appreciate any ideas, suggestions, or a workaround to make it work.

**LWC in Gmail:-**

[image]

**Code:-**

```
// html
<a onclick={filePreview}> Navigate To File </a>

// JS file code
filePreview(event) {
event.preventDefault();
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__namedPage',
    attributes: {
        pageName: 'filePreview'
    },
    state: {
        selectedRecordId: **ContentDocumentId**
    }
})
```

}

Comment: `lightning-navigation` is only available in Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, and the Salesforce Mobile App.  See docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewSouther